# Jquery - Adding a Class to a <td> if it Contains a Link Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with the standard posts calendar that comes with Wordpress and styling it for a client. One thing it doesn't do is add a class name to a `<td>` when it contains a link (meaning there was a post on that date).

I thought that seemed very well within my JQUERY knowledge, but it's just not working.

The HTML the plugin generates looks something like this (abbreviated):

```
<table id="wp-calendar">
<tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="link-to-post">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><a href="link-to-post">6</td>
    <td>7</td>
</table>
```

So, obviously, there were blog posts on the 3rd and 6th of this particular month.

I need to style the `<td>` that contains a link.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").has("a").addClass("featured-date");
    });
</script>
```

And:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").has("a").css("background-color","#c981ae");
    });
</script>
```

I have tried being both more- and less-specific with the selectors. (e.g. `$('#wp-calendar td')`). I have tried adding it both to the end of the sidebar.php file (where the widget will be loaded) and to the wp-footer.php file.

Any help would be super-appreciated.

Comment: given that its word press try looking for any css in the template that may be overriding yours

Comment: The code looks like it should work. Have you made sure that the code actually run (by adding a `console.log` or something), and that the class is indeed not added and there is just some problem in your CSS?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/o75q934w/

Comment: Could you double check if jquery library is included?

Comment: And the standard question: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you friends. I am a dolt. I hadn't added jquery to the header. <embarrassed>

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is not valid markup. You need to close your anchor tags.

This is what worked for me:

```
<table id="wp-calendar">
    <tbody>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><a href="link-to-post">3</a></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><a href="link-to-post">6</a></td>
        <td>7</td>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").has("a").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/onbjerg/qc3ew667/

Comment: still seems to be working with the invalid markup here http://jsfiddle.net/qc3ew667/1/

Comment: Thanks. That was the result of quick typing on my part. The html berated is fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'm an idiot. I hadn't properly embedded JQUERY in the head.

Thank you guys!